# Python strip. can't strip newlines but using f.read()

Tags: python, newline, whitespace, strip

Such a simple action, but I canoot get this to work!!!..

If I have a file that has a number of lines containing text, I want to strip all newlines and whitespace and have a single contigous string from the contents of the file. I've written a very simple python script to do this but it's not working and I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong. :/

file contents look like:

```
1244X 2222 555
141234X 
 2332X
2354235X
235235  X235 5233 5 523
```

code

```
import sys file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file, 'r') as infile:
 data = infile.read()
 clean_data = data.rstrip('\n')
 print clean_data
```

prints out:

```
1244X 2222 555
141234X 
 2332X
2354235X
235235  X235 5233 5 523
```

when I want;

```
1244X2222555141234X2332X2354235X235235X23552335523
```

I have tried `strip()`, `strip(\n\r)` as well as `rstrip()`..

Obviously I'm doing something stupid, but please can someone point out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> with open('hello.txt') as f:
...     f.read().replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')
... 
'1244X2222555141234X2332X2354235X235235X23552335523'
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> with open('hello.txt') as f:
...     ''.join(f.read().split())
... 
'1244X2222555141234X2332X2354235X235235X23552335523'
>>>
```

Comment: `strip` will only strip the whitespace on the two edges of t he string. The whitespace in the middle of the string won't be affected.@user1995839

Answer (score 0):

rstrip or lstrip or strip only removes whitespaces from edges.

Do this to clean up the whitespaces inside of a string.

```
import sys 
file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file, 'r') as infile:
 data = infile.read()
 clean_data = ''.join(data.split())
 print clean_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
with open("file") as in_file:
    data = in_file.read().strip().replace("\n", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach didn't work even for the final `\n` character because you stripped it and `print` introduced it again. This change in your code would have gotten you closer:

```
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

That's a general technique to avoid printing new lines or spaces. In Python 3 you can also use `print(string, end="")`. But that would still not have removed the spaces, as others said. There are already good solutions, but you can also use `translate` for conciseness:

In Python 2:

```
fh.read().translate(None, '\n ')
```

In Python 3:

```
fh.read().translate(str.maketrans("", "", '\n '))
```